# Why does my change in .profile has no effect?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I have a Red-hat Linux box. I logged in as a `user1` and made JBOSS_HOME variable change in `.profile` file.
Previously It was:

```
export JBOSS_HOME="/opt/home/user1/jboss-eap-6.1"
```

Now I changed it to:

```
export JBOSS_HOME="/opt/home/user1/jboss-6.1"
```

But when I am doing:

```
echo $JBOSS_HOME
```

I am getting:

```
/opt/home/user1/jboss-eap-6.1
```

Why is variable untouched?

Comment: you've logout/login or re read .profile ? (`. ./.profile` ) ?

Comment: What did you do after changing the file? Are there any other places where the variable is set?

Comment: No Only `.profile` file have that declared

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to get the change to happen by sourcing your `.profile`:

```
source .profile
```

Comment: Nothing besides this has worked for me. From restarting terminals to logging back in, this seemed to do the trick. It would be nice to also link to some documentation over the command too.

Answer (score 1):

be careful, may be you have same variable in .bash_profile. File .bash_profile rewrites .profile.

you don't need to use `export` command in .profile
just type:
`JBOSS_HOME="/opt/home/user1/jboss-6.1"`

then use:

`[root@example.com ~]# reset`

or

`[root@example.com ~]# source .profile`

Comment: No such file in home directory